# How can I Pbpaste an image in to the command line?

Tags: macos, images, copy-paste, terminal.app

Current use case:

1. I select "copy image" on some random png in safari.
2. I type pbpaste into terminal, and get the link to the image.

Is there anyway to get the binary data instead?

Answer (score 28):

There is a utility just for your use case: pngpaste

https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste

You can install (a bit older) version using `brew install pngpaste`, or just git clone/make latest version.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: use this repo, which has pngcopy and more recent updates: https://github.com/moicci/pngpaste   Also one needs xcode 8 to compile. But I was able to change the codes and went through xcode 7 on my Yosemite somehow.

Comment: Beware this though: https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste/issues/16

Comment: This solution has color issues, please check the link @HappyFace posted.

Comment: @JerryT Does your version also have color issues? If not, can you please publish it on brew as well?

Comment: A made a small edit since many who arrive here via google may not be experts (but regular macOS users).

Answer (score 5):

When you copy an image, OS X actually doesn't copy just the raw image data. In fact, there exist multiple pasteboards in Cocoa, in which there are multiple representations of your image.

Your only options with `pbpaste` are to choose which pasteboard to access, but not which type of content. While the raw hexadecimal `NSData` is stored somewhere in the pasteboard to be pasted to image editing tools, you can't `pbpaste` it to a terminal which would only accept text. From the [`pbpaste` manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html):

> It normally looks first  for plain text data in the pasteboard and writes that to the standard output

Since plain text data is available as the image's URL, you'll always paste that, no matter what.

> There is no way to tell pbpaste to get only a specified data type.

And just for completeness, here's the URL stored for an image, for example:

[image]

Screenshot taken with [Pasteboard Inspector](http://download.cnet.com/Pasteboard-Inspector/3000-2247_4-54643.html).

Answer (score 1):

Copied from my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418045/282215).

---

You need to have `gmktemp` (GNU `mktemp`) installed. (Using, e.g., `brew install coreutils`.)

The following is `zsh` code; It might or might not work with `bash`.

```bsh
pngpaste () {
    local name="${1}" extension="${2:-png}" class="${3}" 
    test -z "$class" && class='«class PNGf»' 
    local stdout='' 
    if [[ "$name" == '-' ]]
    then
        name="$(gmktemp --suffix ".${extension}")"  || return $?
        stdout=y 
    fi
    local dir
    dir="$(dirname "$name")" 
    if test -z "$dir"
    then
        dir="$PWD" 
    fi
    dir="$(realpath "$dir")" 
    mkdir -p "$dir" || return $?
    name="$(basename "$name")" 
    if test -z "${name}"
    then
        name+="some"  || return $?
    fi
    [[ "$name" =~ '\.'${extension}'$' ]] || name+=".${extension}" 
    local f="${dir}/${name}" 
    if test -e "$f"
    then
        command rm "$f"
    fi
    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as ${class}) to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"${dir}\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})" || return $?
    if test -n "$stdout"
    then
        cat "$f"
        command rm "$f"
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```
pngpaste some_path.png
```

```
pngpaste - | base64
```

Comment: It's nice, but unfortunately it will require a roundtrip on the drive, so this will not allow to pipe the data into another program without writing the file on the hard drive.

Comment: @MartinBraun Can you elaborate on why you absolutely need to not use temp files? You're using macOS, so you obviously are not doing some big data work with this. The performance difference should be negligible. You don't even know if the original tool used temp files or not. Anyhow, if you insist, search/ask for help on piping the data from Applescript, as the code to get the image data is in the answer already.

Comment: The original tool is not using temp files, the [source code](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) can be looked at on GitHub. Exclusive data on the RAM will leave no footprint which can be useful when viewing sensitive image data from pages like WikiLeaks within the TorBrowser. This solution would allow to base64 encode such data which can be stored in KeePass, so there will be absolutely no trace, except for pagefile data which should be overwritten, regularly. Also a RAM only solution would be a nice proof-of-concept.

Comment: Could you please provide a solution in which you pipe from the Applescript without creating a temporary file? I really want to give the bounty to you. :)

Comment: @MartinBraun That's a valid use case. I don't know Applescript at all, so your best bet is to ask a new question, "Applescript: How do I pipe binary data to the stdout?". Include the current AS snippet in that question. You can also take a look at https://github.com/casouri/pbcopyf , which uses swift to access the macOS clipboard.

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't want that bounty. I've seen your solution on that other thread before opening this bounty in the hope that someone would provide such solution without writing temporary files. If I create a new question I cannot transfer the bounty. But so be it. I'll probably do as you told me in the case that nobody will provide a solution that fulfills the bounty requirements. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try opening image in a hex editor to access the raw file, I've used Hex Fiend on my mac and it does the job.

http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

Comment: That requires you to save the image first.